# how to mock AuthenticateAsync on AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, mocking, nsubstitute

i have an action on a controller which calls

```
var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
```

i'm trying to mock this result in a unit test like so

```
httpContextMock.AuthenticateAsync(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(AuthenticateResult.Success(...
```

however that throws an `InvalidOperationException`

> "No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.IAuthenticationService' has been registered"

what is the correct way to mock this method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That [extension method](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/rel/2.0.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions/AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.cs#L22)

```
/// <summary>
/// Extension method for authenticate.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">The <see cref="HttpContext"/> context.</param>
/// <param name="scheme">The name of the authentication scheme.</param>
/// <returns>The <see cref="AuthenticateResult"/>.</returns>
public static Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync(this HttpContext context, string scheme) =>
    context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAuthenticationService>().AuthenticateAsync(context, scheme);
```

goes through the [`IServiceProvider RequestServices`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/rel/2.0.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/HttpContext.cs#L64) property.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the <see cref="IServiceProvider"/> that provides access to the request's service container.
/// </summary>
public abstract IServiceProvider RequestServices { get; set; }
```

Mock the service provider to return a mocked `IAuthenticationService` and you should be able to fake your way through the test.

```
authServiceMock.AuthenticateAsync(Arg.Any<HttpContext>(), Arg.Any<string>())
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success()));
providerMock.GetService(typeof(IAuthenticationService))
    .Returns(authServiceMock);
httpContextMock.RequestServices.Returns(providerMock);

//...
```

Comment: thanks for that. i hadnt noticed the RequestServices method to return the mocked services. cheers.

Comment: Not certain what version of .NET this is, but using version 3.1 I get the following error  "The type arguemtn fro method 'Task.FromResult<TResult>(TResult)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try Specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: I can change the method to `FromResult<AuthenticateResult>(AuthenticateResult.Success)` but then I get an error  'cannot convert from method group to ActionResult (too late to edit in further details)